# Need .htaccess recipe to display rss feed dynamically

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently use the following recipe to route .rss files to a script that produces a rss feed dynamically:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).rss$ /get-feed.pl?item=$1
```

It works perfectly for URLs like this:

```
www.example.com/articles.rss
```

What I would to like to do is change the URL to this:

```
www.example.com/rss/articles/
```

Everything I have tried doesn't work.

Comment: "Everything I have tried doesn't work." - What have you tried? In what way did these not work? What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I just tried to put some slashes in the recipe but I'm not an expert in these recipes so they didn't work.  Somethig like this didn't work: RewriteRule ^/rss/(.*)/$ /get-feed.pl?item=$1

Comment: The path RewriteRule matches against never starts with a leading slash, when configured in .htaccess context.

Comment: Any idea how to solve it?  I can't seem to make it match a subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

> I just tried to put some slashes in the recipe but I'm not an expert in these recipes so they didn't work. Somethig like this didn't work: `RewriteRule ^/rss/(.*)/$ /get-feed.pl?item=$1`

("recipe" = regular expression / "regex" for short OR [`RewriteRule` "pattern" from the Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) - At least I think that is what you are referring to? We are not baking a cake here! ;) )

That is very close, except that the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against does not start with a slash when used in a `.htaccess` (directory) context. So, it would need to be like this: `^rss/(.*)/$`. If you had looked to see what your first rule was returning you would have seen that there was no slash prefix in the backreference that was captured (ie. the value of the `item` URL parameter).

However, there are other (minor) issues here...

- The 2nd path segment cannot be empty, so it would be preferable to match *something*, rather than *anything*. eg. `(.+)` instead of `(.*)`. However, this should be made more restrictive, so to match just a single path segement, instead of any URL-path (which is likely to fail anyway I suspect). eg. Presumably `/rss/foo/bar/baz/` should not match?
- Again, if you only want to match a string of the form `articles` then make the regex more restrictive so that it only matches letters (or perhaps letters + numbers + hyphens)?
- You are missing the `L` (`last`) flag on this rule, which is a problem if you have other directives that follow.

So, if you are wanting to rewrite URLs of the form `www.example.com/rss/articles/` (note the trailing slash) then try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^rss/([\w-]+)/$ /get-feed.pl?item=$1 [L]
```

Make sure the browser cache is cleared before testing.

And this would need to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* any existing rewrites.

---

*Aside:* A quick look at your original directive:

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*).rss$ /get-feed.pl?item=$1
> ```

This is not strictly correct, as it potentially matches too much. The unescaped dot before `rss` matches *any* character. And the `.*` subpattern matches 0 or more characters of anything - it must be *something*. So, this should really be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)\.rss$ /get-feed.pl?item=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Incredible.  Thanks for the detailed response.  What a lesson. I have a question.  When I use this it works, but if I redirect 301 /articles.rss  /rss/articles/, the URL ends up as /articles/?item=articles in the browser.  If I don't use a redirect and simply load /rss/articles/ it works fine. Any idea why that is?